# How to "persist in memory" a change in an bean Instance on Grails Controller

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I try to make some modifications in an bean instance of a controller using Grails:

GSP:

```
 g:select name="item" noSelection="${['null':'Select...']}"       
 from="${Item.list()}" optionValue="name" optionKey="id"/>


 g:submitToRemote url="[controller:'Person', action:'addItem']"
 update="itemsPerson" value="Add"/>
```

.....

PersonController:

```
def addItem(Person person){     

Item item = Item.findItemById(params.item);     
person.addToItens(item);

println person.itens.size() "**ever time has only one item!**"
```

}

The problem is when I add the items to person, the state of the Person object doesn't persists the item, ever time when the method addItem is called, person.items is empty again. I know that i can put person in session, but there is another way to keep items list in person?

Comment: Is it possible to post the domain structure of Person and Item, from where this person object gets retrieved?

Comment: My guess is that each time the items gets associated with different person objects!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the observation:

> Save() is not called after person is edited

Try putting in your code, then verify again:

```
person.save(flush:true)
```

Also you may want to put some logs to make sure `findItemById()` return the correct `item`